# How to use kubectl with system:anonymous account without using impersonation with `--as=system:anonymous`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, cloud

> How to use `kubectl` with system:anonymous account without using impersonation with `--as=system:anonymous`?

How can I send requests with `kubectl` using the `system:anonymous` account?

I've tried using the `--as=` option, but this requires that the `default` service account has impersonation privileges, which it doesn't by default.

The only way I currently can send anonymous requests is by using `curl`.

Comment: For me it's not clear what are you trying to achieve? Can you include more details in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a new configuration context that doesn't specify any authentication information and then use `--context whatever`. Or just use curl, that's honestly fine too since I'm really hoping this is just to confirm some security settings or similar. If you run kubectl with `-v 10000000` (or some other huge number) it will actually show you the equivalent curl command to the request it is making.

Comment: Thanks @coderanger, this is indeed just to test things and play with Kubernetes security.  I didn't knew of the `curl` command generation, that makes things much easier, since I created those manually before. Please see my updated post with my current context. Should't this use anonymous? It instead uses `default` service account.

Comment: Are you doing this from inside the cluster? All client libraries (including client-go) automatically default to the ambient service account if present. You can use `automountServiceAccountToken: false` in your pod spec to create a container with no SA.

Comment: Yes, @coderanger, I'm doing this from inside the cluster, from a pod. Will `automountServiceAccountToken: false` make `kubectl` send requests anonymously?

Comment: It should, yes. In that there won't be default creds anymore. But seriously, just use curl.